# Django django-location-field missing API Keys

Tags: python, django, google-maps

I am using the https://github.com/caioariede/django-location-field library to build a Location View using Django. The issue is that I can't find a documentation saying how to define my own Google Maps API KEY.

This is the code I have on my settings.py:

```
LOCATION_FIELD_PATH = STATIC_URL + 'location_field'
LOCATION_FIELD = {
    'map.provider': 'google',
    'map.zoom': 13,

    'search.provider': 'google',
    'search.suffix': '',

    # Google
    'provider.google.api': '//maps.google.com/maps/api/js',
    'provider.google.api_key': 'MY_API_KEY_HERE',
    'provider.google.map_type': 'ROADMAP',


    # misc
    'resources.root_path': LOCATION_FIELD_PATH,
    'resources.media': {
        'js': [
           LOCATION_FIELD_PATH + '/js/jquery.livequery.js',
            LOCATION_FIELD_PATH + '/js/form.js',
        ],
    },
}
```

But this solution dose not seem to work.

```
maps.google.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/28/11/util.js:219 Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys
```

I have been searching for a while now, but no luck in getting the answer.

[image: Error I get]

Answer (score 1):

You may use [django-geoposition](https://github.com/philippbosch/django-geoposition) instead of [django-location-field](https://github.com/caioariede/django-location-field). It has the same functionality and also has a simple documentation https://django-geoposition.readthedocs.io/en/latest/.

You can find how to define your Google Maps API KEY in https://django-geoposition.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#installation.

Comment: Thanks! Although, I'm working on an existing system and it has several thousands of entries already for the django-location-field model and migrate the data to another model will be a bit complicated.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add the following to the settings.py file:

`GOOGLE_MAPS_V3_APIKEY = 'YOUR_API_KEY_HERE'`