# Can not migrate schema django-geoposition

Tags: python, django, django-geoposition

I can `makemigrations`, but can not `migrate` the schema.

django-geoposition==0.3.0
django==1.11.5
python3.6.2
PostgreSQL 9.6.5 on x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0, compiled by Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.1.76), 64-bit

```
import environ
env = environ.Env()

...
DATABASES = {
    'default': env.db("DATABASE_URL", default="postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/soken_web")
}
DATABASES['default']['ATOMIC_REQUESTS'] = True
DATABASES['default']['ENGINE'] = 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis'
GEOPOSITION_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY = '<API_KEY>'
GEOPOSITION_MAP_OPTIONS = {
    'minZoom': 3,
    'maxZoom': 15,
}

GEOPOSITION_MARKER_OPTIONS = {
    'cursor': 'move'
}


INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'geoposition',
]
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
from geoposition.fields import GeopositionField


class House(models.Model):
    ...
    location = GeopositionField()
```

**Problem:**

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: data type character varying has no default operator class for access method "gist"
HINT:  You must specify an operator class for the index or define a default operator class for the data type.
```

**References:**
[Django django-location-field missing API Keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43660655/django-django-location-field-missing-api-keys)
https://github.com/caioariede/django-location-field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using postgres you need probably to install gist module as said at the docs:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/btree-gist.html

> You can use the btree_gist extension to define exclusion constraints
>   on plain scalar data types, which can then be combined with range
>   exclusions for maximum flexibility. For example, after btree_gist is
>   installed, the following constraint will reject overlapping ranges
>   only if the meeting room numbers are equal:

Comment: SO let me accept after 4 minutes. Please wait. Thank you very much.